# Adding a ‘If Product Attribute is then" code

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m trying to edit this code as so

If
Product Attribute Scanned text is `Image is a stock photo`
Then do this code

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .woocommerce #content div.product div.images,
  .woocommerce div.product div.images,
  .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images,
  .woocommerce-page div.product div.images {
     width: 30%;
  }
  .woocommerce #content div.product div.summary,
  .woocommerce div.product div.summary,
  .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.summary,
  .woocommerce-page div.product div.summary {
     float: right;
     width: 65%;
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can implement this? It’s a fix I’ve found that works with my website to specific listings.

This is on Wordpages using WooCommerce

Thank you.

Example page is 
https://kantomart.com/shop/60/

Comment: @frobinsonj Are you sure he is asking to target using CSS? This looks more look WordPress/Woocommerce conditional logic.

Comment: From what i've read online it seems WooCommerce is a lot more complicated to pull that information from

Comment: @ManojKumar Ah, I seem to have misunderstood, thought he meant html attributes. Thanks.